# Sending an email via SQL Server causes error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to send an e-mail via SQL Server Management Studio, but it returns an error.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',
     @recipients = 'example@example.com',
     @body = 'The stored procedure finished successfully.',
     @subject = 'Automated Success Message'
```

Error is:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

I've surfed the internet to fix this problem, but none worked out. Need your help. Thanks

Comment: `grant execute on dbo.sp_send_dbmail to <usernamehere>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your user do not have correct rights on the SQL instance you are targeting, as suggested in the comments :

```
grant execute on dbo.sp_send_dbmail to <usernamehere>;
```

See the [Troubleshooting article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188719%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on this issue :

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'DatabaseMailUserRole'
    ,@membername = '<user or role name>';
GO
```

Also, you may have not configured this feature, see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) :

> Before use, Database Mail must be enabled using the Database Mail
>   Configuration Wizard, or sp_configure.

And [this one](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/SQLServer/DBA_tips/Database_Administration/DBA_22.shtml) for configuration :

```
USE master
Go

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
Go

RECONFIGURE
Go

EXEC sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1
Go

RECONFIGURE
Go

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
Go

RECONFIGURE
Go
```

Comment: Yep, configvalue in Database Mail XPs is set to 0, how to change it?

Comment: Now, the most stupid question on stackoverflow ever: How do I learn what is my username?))

Comment: @SherzodMuminov Think about accepting the answer if that solved you problem ;)